# Примитивно-рекурсивный алгоритм

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте интересует вопрос , может кто сталкивался 
Существует ли примитивно рекурсивный алгоритм у данной задачи ?

"Являются ли числа n и m+n простыми?"

или вообще какой либо алгоритм. Если нет то конечно и примитивно - рекурсивного не будет

Comment: Простыми или **взаимно** простыми?

Comment: Если взаимно простыми, то в рекурсию попадает идеально.

Comment: В задании написанно "простыми" и ничего больше

Comment: вы мне закрываете новые темы , а как получить тут ответ то если ее уже никто не видит.